# What CDK resource can I use to create an ec2 Image Builder ContainerRecipe? I only see a way to create an ImageRecipe via CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I can't seem to find a resource that will allow me to build a containerRecipe, only an imageRecipe in EC2 Image Builder. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-imagebuilder-readme.html

Note: I am using the typescript cdk.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this functionality exists now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_imagebuilder.CfnContainerRecipe.html